# Jupyter’s kernel crash when i use groupby

Tags: python, pandas, crash

I’m analizing a dataset with 200 columns and 6000 rows. I computed all the possibile differences between columns using iterools and implemented them into the dataset. So now the number of columns has increased. Until now everything work fine and kernel doesn’t have problems. Kernel dies when i try to group columns with same first value and sum them.

```
#difference between two columns,all possible combinations 1-2,1-3,..,199-200

def sb(df):
    comb=itertools.permutations(df.columns,2)
    N_f=pd.DataFrame()
    N_f = pd.concat([df[a]-df[b] for a,b in comb],axis=1)
    N_f.iloc[0,:]=[abs(number) for number in N_f.iloc[0,:]]
    return N_f
#Here i transform the first row into columns headers and then i try to sum columns with the same head

def fg(m):
    f.columns=f.iloc[0]
    f=f.iloc[1:]
    f=f.groupby(f.columns,axis=1).sum()
    return f
```

Now i tried to run the code without the groupby part, but the kernel keeps dying.

Comment: We need enough details and examples to reproduce your issue, otherwise it just becomes a guessing game that isn't helpful for anybody.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel crashes often suggest a large spike in resource usage, which your machine and/or juypter configuration could not handle.

The question is then, "What am I doing that is using so many resources?".

That's for you to figure out, but my guess is that it has to do with your list comprehension over permutations. Permutations are extremely expensive, and having in-memory data structures for each permutation is going to hurt.

I suggest debugging like so:

```py
# Print out the size of this. Does it surprise you?
comb=itertools.permutations(df.columns,2)

N_f=pd.DataFrame()

# Instead of doing these operations in one list comprehension,
# instead make a for loop and print out the memory
# usage at each iteration in the loop.
# How is it scaling?
N_f = pd.concat([df[a]-df[b] for a,b in comb],axis=1)
```